# How to retrieve content of an external folder?

Tags: php, curl

I am developping a CMS with a system of plugin.

And I want to allow people (who have the CMS on their web host) to download plugin directly from my web server.

So I know how to use cURL to retrieve content of a file, but how can I download a complete folder ?

Comment: you can't, not directly. get a list of the files in the folder (one curl request), then issue a curl request for each file individually.

Comment: You need to compress the folder, then decompress it using tar. Don't waste bandwidth downloading one file at a time.

Comment: Okay, and the ZipArchive module is native (comes with PHP) ?

Comment: @MTC see [http://php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php)